# contracts/FlashLoan DeclarationError: Identifier already declared

Tags: solidity, remix, declaration

Error message

```
contracts/FlashLoanReceiverBase.sol:9:1: DeclarationError: Identifier already declared.
import "./Withdrawable.sol";
^--------------------------^
github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/docs-v3.x/contracts/utils/Address.sol:8:1: The previous declaration is here:
library Address {
^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
```

Source

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: AGPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.8.0;
 
import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/docs-v3.x/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/docs-v3.x/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/docs-v3.x/contracts/token/ERC20/SafeERC20.sol";
import "./IFlashLoanReceiver.sol";
import "./ILendingPoolAddressesProvider.sol";
import "./Withdrawable.sol";


abstract contract FlashLoanReceiverBaseV1 is IFlashLoanReceiverV1, Withdrawable {

    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    address constant ethAddress = 0xEeeeeEeeeEeEeeEeEeEeeEEEeeeeEeeeeeeeEEeE;
    ILendingPoolAddressesProviderV1 public addressesProvider;

    constructor(address _addressProvider) public {
        addressesProvider = ILendingPoolAddressesProviderV1(_addressProvider);
    }

    receive() payable external {}

    function transferFundsBackToPoolInternal(address _reserve, uint256 _amount) internal {
        address payable core = addressesProvider.getLendingPoolCore();
        transferInternal(core, _reserve, _amount);
    }

    function transferInternal(address payable _destination, address _reserve, uint256 _amount) internal {
        if(_reserve == ethAddress) {
            (bool success, ) = _destination.call{value: _amount}("");
            require(success == true, "Couldn't transfer ETH");
            return;
        }
        IERC20(_reserve).safeTransfer(_destination, _amount);
    }

    function getBalanceInternal(address _target, address _reserve) internal view returns(uint256) {
        if(_reserve == ethAddress) {
            return _target.balance;
        }
        return IERC20(_reserve).balanceOf(_target);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, provide the whole code so we can try compiling.

Comment: if you could help i would be thankful

Comment: The supplied part compiles just fine, the issue should be in the other files: "IFlashLoanReceiver.sol", "ILendingPoolAddressesProvider.sol" or "Withdrawable.sol".